# SQL Alchemy inspect module giving table names in lower case

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-3.9

Here is how am getting table names for a schema using sql alchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
inspector = inspect(engine)

table_list = inspector.get_table_names(schema="PUBLIC")
```

this gives me table names in lower case but actually tables exist with capital case in database, so i want to get table names with same case in which they exist in database/schema

**Note:** using snowflake database

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @GordThompson snowflake

Comment: Have you created your tables using regular or delimited identifiers?

Comment: @IljaEverilä with quoted identifiers

Comment: That's very interesting then. The SQLA dialect should not touch case in that ... case. When it comes to unquoted, Snowflake stores (and resolves) them in upper case. SQLA on the other hand treats all lower case as "unquoted".

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not SQLAlchemy does "case normalization" is left up to the dialect because normalization can be convenient for some databases and a nuisance for others.

For example, the `mssql+pyodbc://` dialect does not force table names to lower case:

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MY_TABLE")
    conn.exec_driver_sql("CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (id int primary key)")

insp = sa.inspect(engine)
print(insp.get_table_names())
# ['MY_TABLE', 'tbl_main', 'tbl_temp']
```

You will probably have to ask the developers of [snowflake-sqlalchemy](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy) about this.

Answer (score 0):

In snowflake database, I just checked by creating tables with different cases and what i noticed is that if we create table with small/upper case name like (test/TEST) then SqlAlchemy returns name with small case in get_table_name method but if we create table with name having mix cases like (TestAbc) then it returns exact case so i think we can simply convert table names with lower case to upper after getting it from sql alchmey metadata/inspect method